# Inconsistent result of WifiInfo#getBssid() behavior

Tags: android, qt

I am trying to define WiFi connection state on its changing. But I need a bit more - to get BSSID for WiFi network.

I didn't use BroadcastReceiver approach, instead I just poll WifiInfo#getBssid() every second. Most of time it works correct, but after my phone goes sleep for relatively long time (>~hour) WifiInfo#getBssid() returns null when my phon is connected to the WiFi.

```
public String getBssid() {
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager);
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    String bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
}
```

I call this function from Qt code via JNI.

Comment: If Android is anything, it's inconsistent. Have you looked into how Android's Doze work? I'm pretty sure it disables WiFi (sort of, not really, it's complicated), which might be your issue. Where is this code being run from?

Comment: @TheWanderer, I have only general understanding of Doze. This code is in MainActitvity which is a wrapper for a Qt application.

Comment: Any time you want to do background work, you need to use a Service.

Comment: Well.. It's true for Android SDK and official application architecture where Activities and Services states are managed by Android. I use Qt, where I manage of component's state myself.
Anyway, what is the reason for all of these if I just call getBssid() every second when the app is active (Activity in in foreground)?

Comment: It's probably because of Doze. Try using a partial wakelock.

Comment: OK, @TheWanderer, I'll try, but I just don't understand the reason - I don't need for any result in background, I call getBssid() in active state of the activity.. So there is nothing to lock and be locked..

Comment: because Doze effectively disables WiFi to save battery.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean that my request can be issued when wifi is still locked.. OK, thank you, I will try!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in Android but in Qt. I used QNetworkConfigurationManager as a member of my NetworkMonitor class and checked `QNetworkConfigurationManager#defaultConfiguration().bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN` prior to check bssid. So, the bearerType was returning wrong value after device sleep-wakeup until I implemented recreation of QNetworkConfigurationManager instance on every wakeup.